# Import model from 3DSlicer into Unity automatically

Tags: python, matlab, dicom, medical

For my bachelor thesis I have to convert DICOM data to a 3d model and import this into unity so I can create a virtual reality. So the data out of 3DSlicer has to be updated in Unity automatically. You can say I have to link the two programs. What do you think is the best way to do this? Should I create a Matlab or Python module or is there a better way?

I am sorry if there is already a similar question but I have searched for answers on the internet and unfortunately I couldn't find an answer.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since slicer is compatible to python codes. you can try to access to the unity codes, if you use ubuntu it is probably easier to use a shell script to call the unity functions you need withing the python codes of slicer.

I did it with ANSYS softwares to link two different softwares together and export an output from the first software and pass it to the second software.

Rather than this automatic way, this is a guideline about how to export data from other apps to Unity

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html